# How to include user fonts

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have an app in flutter where I have used custom font from Google fonts. These fonts are included in the `fonts` folder and I have imported in `pubspec.yaml` like so,

```
fonts:
  - family: Source Sans Pro
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf
    weight: 400
    - asset: fonts/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf
    weight: 600
    - asset: fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf
    weight: 700
    - asset: fonts/SourceSansPro-Black.ttf
    weight: 900
```

But I want the users to be able to add their own fonts (TTf files). I can ask them to pick the TTf file and save it in `appsDocDirectory`, after this, how can I use the font in the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: got from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55458

```
Future<ByteData> loadFont(String path) async{
      File file = File(path);
      Uint8List bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
      return ByteData.view(bytes.buffer);
    }
    
    var custom = FontLoader('Pacifico');
    custom.addFont(loadFont("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Pacifico-Regular.ttf"));
    await custom.load();
    setState(() {});
```

Edit:

now your font will be available as `'Pacifico'` after `await custom.load();` completes